# get fire store reference data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in using firebase as backend to my flutter app and I have a question how to link two documents together and get both data at same time for example I have a user collection and post collection how I link both and when I get post data I also get user data in the same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective looks like a `JOIN` query in a SQL database. Unfortunately, there is **no** `JOIN` query in **Firestore** - a NoSQL database. It is also mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666799/8753991) that Firestore does not have the concept of a server-side JOIN.

There are ways that you can still do it like the following answers below:

1. [number one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110768/8753991): You will have to query them individually then combine the two documents or to get data from multiple collections, you will need to perform multiple read operations. I think these are some examples of it: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610407/how-to-merge-data-from-two-collections-in-firestore) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52878285/8753991) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645366/8753991).
2. [number two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65102658/8753991): Remodeling your database that you can perform a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: from what you say i guess that's not the optimal solution for social media